# Using timer behind multiple alerts and prompts

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a game that I am making using only pure javascript. Instead of a GUI, It is more like the old  command line games and uses a prompt for input.

One of the main components of it is the Clock, which is expressed in hours, and can be checked with the commmand "time" and tells them the value of the variable "time". Here is the code:

```
var timestrt = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function(){timestrt++;return timestrt;}, 86000); var time = timestrt;
```

After testing it, I realized that the clock was not changing. So I set it to 10 seconds instead of 86 to be sure that I was waiting long enough, and it still did not want to work

I know that it is probably caused by the prompt and constant alerts, but I am not sure even where to start for a workaround.
Any ideas?

Edit: is it possible to either 
1. retrieve the timer from an external page 
2. comparing it to an actual clock in real time or 
3. Using a animated gif clock in the background and calculating the location of certain pixels as time?

Comment: Before anyone answers, I know that there will be a lot of "you can't do that" or "that's not possible". I am looking for advice or a workaround, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The alerts are in a different part of the code in a SWITCH that checks against the user input from the prompt. I only code i supplied is what i thought woud help solve the problem.

Comment: also, you are not returning anything on your timer function, you are just setting some variables and increasing your timestrt global but only on your function scope, maybe a return timestrat instead of setting it to time variable?, also your function will repeat every 86 seconds is that what you want?

Comment: Your main problem is that you are using alerts. When using alerts, the script execution is paused on each `alert()` or `prompt()`. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/3st829pz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my workaround:

This code is called before the prompt is started:

```
function initTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    stS = now.getSeconds();
    stM = now.getMinutes();
    stH = now.getHours();
   }
```

This is called after the prompt is done:

```
function computeTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var reS = now.getSeconds();
    var reM = now.getMinutes();
    var reH = now.getHours();
    var elapS = reS - stS;
    var elapM = reM - stM;
    var elapH = reH - stH;
    if (elapM < 0) {
        reM = reM + 60;
        elapM = reM - stM;
    }
    if (elapS < 0) {
        reS = reS + 60;
        elapS = reS - stS;
    }
```

Then I convert it to seconds to make it easier to check against:

```
    var finalH = elapH * 3600;
    var finalM = elapM * 60;
    var finalS = finalM + elapS + finalH;
```

And check/change the time variable based on how many sets of 86 seconds has passed:

```
    if (finalS > 86 && finalS < 172) {
        time = 1;
    }
    if (finalS > 172 && finalS < 258) {
        time = 2;
    }
    if (finalS > 258 && finalS < 344) {
        time = 3;
    }
    if (finalS > 344 && finalS < 430) {
        time = 4;
    }
    if (finalS > 430 && finalS < 516) {
        time = 5;
    }
    if (finalS > 516) {
        time = 6;
        alert('5 A.M.');
        alert('A clock is chiming...');
        alert('6 A.M.');
        playing = false;
        alert('Thanks for playing! Goodbye!');
        }
```

And that is my alternative to using a setinterval/timer behind multiple prompts and alerts. The last part probably wasn't needed, but since it answered my original question I included it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the native prompts and dialogs, since they stop the script execution time. Instead use simulated ones, for example [jQuery IU](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) has prompts and dialog boxes that do not stop execution. [Here is an example of that](http://jsfiddle.net/wsq5shuz/):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

    var timestrt = 1;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
      timestrt++;
      var time = timestrt;
      $("#time").text(time);
    }, 1000);    

});
```

Comment: I am trying to create a workaround to help not only myself but all stackoverflow users and the problem is with alerts and prompts. I have a few suggestions at the top but no way to implement them. Thanks for the help, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @ChuckFetch It's not possible with normal alerts or prompts, you must simulate them in some way to provide the same functionality that either alerts of prompts have. This way is the only work around, as mentioned in the comments it's not possible with normal alerts and prompts by default. It may not be the answer you are looking for but it's the only way to do it.